# Rails 3.1 production assets : big files are cut into pieces

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

Since I use Rails 3.1 and the assets pipeline I have a big problem when in production mode.

When I did a bundle exec rake assets:precompile, I had errors like

> 'myjsfile.js' has a invalid UTF-8 byte sequence

in particular with tiny_mce plugin js files.

So I gave up, as everything was working ok in developpment on my mac, and I wrote this line in the production.rb file: `config.assets.compile = true`

The JS files are therefore generated without errors.

On the other hand, there is a big problem with long files, like jquery.js

Regularly, Rails generates only half of the jQuery file, and the only manner I found to fix temporarily the problem is to go on the js file's URL (`http://myapp.com/assets/jquery.js`) and refresh the page many times, and after a while the jquery file is entire again.
Then a few days later the problem is back and I've got to do this again.

In fact, it's as if during the compilation of big files, the process stopped in the middle  and that the server sent the file half compiled.

Have some of you had this problem? Any idea from where it could come?

I use nginx and passenger on an Ubuntu server for production. I never encounter this problem on my Mac.

In advance, thank's for your help !

Answer (score 0):

The pre-compilation process will fail if you run out of memory on your server. Try doing a `rake assets:precompile` on your mac and committing the generated assets so that you can get them on your server.

In the longer run, run the precompile on an intermediate CI server, for every successful build.